# What is the right way to do conditional rendering in React Native + Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Back when I was making apps in React without Redux I would do something like this in Render:

`{!this.state.modalShown?<Component1/>:<Component2/>}`

However it does not seem to work in Redux. This is in App.js component, I'm subscribed to the store and this JSX is wrapped in the Provider.

```
{store.getState().currentRestaurantCode===''||store.getState().currentRestaurantCode==='Bad Request'
 ?<View> Some elements </View>
 :<View> Some other elements </View>
}
```

However, it doesn't work. AM I doing something wrong? New to Redux here.

Comment: Instead of `||` try logical AND `&&`.

Comment: Please add more information. The very first thing you should mention what do you get as a output. Also, have you debugged/checked what value `store.getState().currentRestaurantCode` holds? If, it does not hold the desired value then probably the reducer didn't update properly. Otherwise the syntax looks right.

Comment: This is the right approach to doing the conditional code but instead of doing `store.getState()` can you use `this.props.state` and check whether the condition is proper or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think multiple conditions is making problem here . It is not the issue of redux

Try this

```
const isRestaurantCodeEmpty = store.getState().currentRestaurantCode===''||store.getState().currentRestaurantCode==='Bad Request';

....

{isRestaurantCodeEmpty
 ?<View> Some elements </View>
 :<View> Some other elements </View>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your action and it goes through reducers(you should create action and reducers) then get your data via connect and pass it to your form from mapstatetoprops function. Seems you didn't do these.